# How to decode Javascript _0x Hex

Tags: javascript, hash, hex, decode, decoder

I tried to decode this code but I did not succeed:

```js
var _0x147bb5 = _0xe0c4, _0x41852d = _0xe0c4, _0x39ac2c = _0xe0c4;
(function (_0x3c89e2, _0x4b3ebe) {
    var _0x331330 = _0xe0c4, _0x279707 = _0xe0c4, _0x50917c = _0xe0c4, _0x489044 = _0x3c89e2();
    while (!![]) {
        try {
            var _0x36e386 = -parseInt(_0x331330(0x133)) / 0x1 + -parseInt(_0x279707('0x12a')) / 0x2 + -parseInt(_0x331330(0x111)) / 0x3 + -parseInt(_0x331330(0x12f)) / 0x4 + parseInt(_0x279707('0x10a')) / 0x5 * (-parseInt(_0x279707('0xf1')) / 0x6) + -parseInt(_0x331330('0x109')) / 0x7 + parseInt(_0x331330(0xee)) / 0x8 * (parseInt(_0x279707(0x11a)) / 0x9);
            if (_0x36e386 === _0x4b3ebe) break; else _0x489044['push'](_0x489044['shift']());
        } catch (_0x108487) {
            _0x489044['push'](_0x489044['shift']());
        }
    }
}(_0x5a9e, 0x7f5a2));

var s = _0x147bb5('0x12b') + _0x147bb5(0xdc) + _0x39ac2c('0x118') + '91', f = 0xb, l = lf(), message = _0x39ac2c('0x117') + _0x39ac2c('0xe7') + _0x39ac2c('0x108') + _0x147bb5('0xd4') + 'ot\x20' + _0x147bb5('0x104') + _0x41852d(0xd3) + _0x39ac2c('0x122') + _0x39ac2c('0xef') + _0x41852d(0x127) + _0x41852d('0x102') + _0x41852d('0xfb') + _0x147bb5(0xe2) + _0x39ac2c(0xf2) + _0x147bb5(0xe5) + _0x41852d(0xd6) + _0x39ac2c(0x125) + _0x41852d(0xff) + _0x147bb5(0xd7) + _0x41852d('0x110') + _0x39ac2c('0x11e') + _0x39ac2c(0xdd) + _0x41852d(0x107) + 'ea)';

function rtclickcheck(_0xf37bcd) {
    var _0x5b07b6 = _0x39ac2c, _0x189d42 = _0x41852d, _0x158d5e = _0x147bb5;
    if (navigator[_0x5b07b6(0xfd) + _0x189d42(0xf5) + 'e'] == _0x158d5e('0xe4') + _0x189d42(0xde) + 'pe' && _0xf37bcd[_0x5b07b6('0xfc') + 'ch'] == 0x3) return alert(message), ![];
    if (navigator[_0x5b07b6(0xfd) + _0x189d42(0xf8) + _0x5b07b6('0x11d') + 'n'][_0x5b07b6('0xec') + _0x158d5e(0x128) + 'f'](_0x158d5e(0xe6) + 'E') != -0x1 && event[_0x189d42('0x126') + _0x158d5e('0x132')] == 0x2) return alert(message), ![];
} function _0x5a9e() {
    var _0x521b96 = ['Thi', '7109872DszjuD', '4405xemFJj', 'deA', '//r', 'cre', 'hre', 'h=/', 're.', '1823784ZeLCWd', ';\x20p', 'etc', 'cap', 'cha', 'crt', 'Ooh', '794', 'TCS', '14494869UZdEDp', 'onm', 'erH', 'sio', 'com', 'ute', 'dli', 'men', 'py\x20', '_y=', 'tBy', 'uth', 'but', 'rot', 'exO', 'inn', '603236FmaGTN', '-11', 'exp', 'ous', 'toU', '2882436fEtPRL', 'dit', 'kie', 'ton', '1000745kgQiEE', '\x20Co', 's\x20N', 'hos', '//y', 'sto', 'len', 'pat', 'tri', '.ly', '350', '\x20(y', 'sca', 'gth', 'lin', 'rib', 'by\x20', 'Att', 'Net', 'ps:', 'MSI', '!!\x20', 'edo', 'ide', 'tna', '10;', 'ind', '/yu', '24DoydZk', '-\x20P', 'rCo', '4518TXMdnf', 'htt', 'N_f', 'Ele', 'Nam', 'and', 'get', 'Ver', 'ire', 'ati', 'ed\x20', 'whi', 'app', 'coo', 'eme', 'TML', 'ath', 'ect', 'sli', 'For', 'Tim', 'set', 'uid'];
    _0x5a9e = function () {
        return _0x521b96;
    };
    return _0x5a9e();
}
document[_0x147bb5(0x11b) + _0x147bb5('0x12d') + _0x147bb5('0xe8') + 'wn'] = rtclickcheck;
if (l == s && s[_0x147bb5(0xd8) + _0x147bb5('0xdf')] == f) {
    var ceditf = document[_0x147bb5(0xf7) + _0x41852d(0xf4) + _0x39ac2c('0x121') + _0x147bb5(0x124) + 'Id'](_0x39ac2c(0x10d) + _0x147bb5('0x130') + _0x147bb5('0xe0') + 'k'), citf = document[_0x39ac2c(0xf7) + _0x147bb5('0xf4') + _0x39ac2c('0x121') + _0x39ac2c('0x124') + 'Id'](_0x39ac2c('0x116') + _0x39ac2c(0xe0) + 'k');
    o();
    var citdf = document[_0x41852d('0xf7') + _0x147bb5('0xf4') + _0x41852d(0x121) + _0x41852d('0x124') + 'Id'](_0x41852d('0x116') + _0x147bb5('0x120') + 'nk');
    function checkLIC() {
        var _0x4072d7 = _0x41852d, _0x264ab4 = _0x41852d, _0x1a0d97 = _0x147bb5;
        if (cedit['inn' + _0x4072d7('0x11c') + _0x4072d7(0x100)][_0x1a0d97('0xd8') + _0x4072d7('0xdf')] === 0x0) return invalidLIC(), ![];
    }
}
var cedit = document[_0x41852d(0xf7) + _0x39ac2c(0xf4) + _0x39ac2c(0x121) + _0x41852d('0x124') + 'Id'](_0x147bb5('0x10d') + _0x39ac2c(0x130) + _0x39ac2c(0xe0) + 'k');
function _0xe0c4(_0x488be0, _0x324154) {
    var _0x5a9e88 = _0x5a9e();
    return _0xe0c4 = function (_0xe0c4a8, _0x3812b4) {
        _0xe0c4a8 = _0xe0c4a8 - 0xd3; var _0x1108f7 = _0x5a9e88[_0xe0c4a8];
        return _0x1108f7;
    }, _0xe0c4(_0x488be0, _0x324154);

}
!cedit && invalidLIC();
function o() {
    _0x162858();
    function _0x162858() {
        var _0x139ac8 = _0xe0c4, _0x75417f = _0xe0c4, _0x15d340 = _0xe0c4, _0x5960f5 = new Date();
        _0x5960f5[_0x139ac8(0x106) + _0x75417f('0x105') + 'e'](_0x5960f5[_0x75417f(0xf7) + _0x15d340(0x105) + 'e']() + 0x15180 * 0x3);
        var _0x43eec0 = _0x75417f(0x12c) + _0x15d340(0xf9) + 's=' + _0x5960f5[_0x15d340('0x12e') + _0x139ac8(0x119) + _0x139ac8(0xda) + 'ng']();
        document[_0x15d340('0xfe') + 'kie'] = _0x15d340(0x114) + _0x139ac8('0x123') + _0x15d340('0xeb') + _0x15d340('0xd9') + _0x75417f('0x10f') + ';', document[_0x75417f(0xfe) + _0x15d340('0x131')] = 'JSO' + _0x139ac8(0xf3) + _0x75417f('0x113') + 'h' + '=' + fetchon + ';' + _0x43eec0 + (_0x139ac8(0x112) + _0x15d340('0x101') + '=/'), window['loc' + _0x15d340(0xfa) + 'on'][_0x15d340('0x10e') + 'f'] = api;
    }
}
function invalidLIC() { }
function checkLIC() {
    var _0x4dac69 = _0x39ac2c, _0x55bc12 = _0x41852d, _0x4c895a = _0x147bb5;
    if (cedit[_0x4dac69(0x129) + _0x4dac69('0x11c') + _0x4c895a(0x100)][_0x55bc12('0xd8') + _0x4dac69(0xdf)] === 0x0) return invalidLIC(), ![]; else {
        if (cedit[_0x4c895a('0xf7') + _0x55bc12(0xe3) + _0x55bc12(0xe1) + _0x4c895a('0x11f')](_0x4dac69(0x10e) + 'f') !== _0x4c895a(0xf2) + _0x4c895a('0xe5') + _0x55bc12('0x10c') + 'ebr' + _0x4c895a('0xf6') + _0x4c895a(0xdb) + _0x55bc12('0xed') + _0x4c895a(0xe9) + 'a/') return invalidLIC(), ![];
    }
}
checkLIC(),
    setInterval(
        function () {
            checkLIC();
        },
        0x1388
    );
function lf() {
    var _0x5a8bac = _0x39ac2c, _0x505e9a = _0x147bb5, _0xd36b1d = _0x147bb5, _0x5b07b5 = location[_0x5a8bac(0xd5) + _0x505e9a('0xea') + 'me'][_0x5a8bac(0x103) + 'ce'](0x2)[_0x505e9a(0x103) + 'ce'](0x0, -0x2) + '24', _0x130606 = 0x0;
    if (_0x5b07b5[_0x5a8bac('0xd8') + _0xd36b1d('0xdf')] == 0x0) return _0x130606;
    for (i = 0x0; i < _0x5b07b5[_0x5a8bac('0xd8') + _0xd36b1d(0xdf)]; i++) {
        char = _0x5b07b5[_0xd36b1d('0x115') + _0xd36b1d('0xf0') + _0xd36b1d(0x10b) + 't'](i), _0x130606 = (_0x130606 << 0x5) - _0x130606 + char, _0x130606 = _0x130606 & _0x130606;
    }
    return _0x130606;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/utpgLw06/

So My first approach is to use online tools, but none of them works. I also try to manually decode it by calling the function name `console.log(_0x331330(0x133))` but it just shows strings that I don't understand. I also tried to decode those strings by using much hex at numerical decoders but none of them works. Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: they are just variables that don't actually mean anything - stop wasting time trying to de-obfuscate code

Comment: If you trying to deobfuscate the var/function name, that is just a (random)hex and doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a bit with this code:

- The `_Ox` names are just variable names. You can make the code more readable by collecting all such distinct names and replace them with more readable names, like `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, ....
- There are two variables referenced which are not defined, `api` and `fetchon`. I suppose that the page where this script runs, has defined them somewhere.
- The first part of the script is harmless and just shuffles an array of strings, which is later used to obfuscate strings (often property names). You can execute it
- The code that needs de-obfuscation is the code that gets/sets properties of `window`, `document`, `nagivator`, ...and other objects. You can get a long way by putting that part of the script in a template literal, and *evaluating* all those expressions that evaluate to a property name, or to a value assigned to a property.
- Functions and immediate code are mixed. It helps to reorganise that a bit.
- Some functions have local variables which are constants and have unique names. These can be moved to the global scope and can often be evaluated safely, so the rest of the function's code can be clarified inside a template literal (like explained above).
- Any remaining variables (not evaluated), can be given more telling names by seeing how they are used.

Anyway, here is the result I got to:

```
function rtclickcheck(e) {
    if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" && e.which == 3) 
        return alert("Ooh!! This Not For Copy - Protected by https://yuthemestore.com (yuidea)"), false;
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) 
        return alert("Ooh!! This Not For Copy - Protected by https://yuthemestore.com (yuidea)"), false;
} 

document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;

function o() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + 259200);
    var expiration = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "cap_y=10;path=/;";
    // fetchon and api must be defined?
    document.cookie = "JSON_fetch=" + fetchon + ";" + expiration + "; path=/";
    window.location.href = api;
}

function invalidLIC() { }

function checkLIC() {
    if (cedit.innerHTML.length === 0) 
        return invalidLIC(), false; 
    else {
        if (cedit.getAttribute("href") !== "https://rebrand.ly/yuidea/") 
            return invalidLIC(), false;
    }
}

function lf() {
    var decrypted = location.hostname.slice(2).slice(0, -2) + '24', 
        encrypted = 0;
    if (decrypted.length == 0) return encrypted;
    for (i = 0; i < decrypted.length; i++) {
        char = decrypted.charCodeAt(i);
        encrypted = (encrypted << 5) - encrypted + char;
        encrypted = encrypted & encrypted;
    }
    return encrypted;
}

var l = lf();
var s = "-1135079491";
if (l == s && s.length == 11) {
    var ceditf = document.getElementById("creditlink"), 
        citf = document.getElementById("crtlink");
    o();
    var citdf = document.getElementById("crtdlink");

    function checkLIC() {
        if (cedit.innerHTML.length === 0) 
            return invalidLIC(), false;
    }
}

var cedit = document.getElementById("creditlink");
!cedit && invalidLIC();
checkLIC();
setInterval(checkLIC, 5000);
```

This code seems to do the following things:

- Avoid that the user can view the source of the page with a right click
- Obfuscates the current site's hostname through bitshifting and summing, and checks that the result has a certain value. I didn't try to find out what the original hostname would have to be to get a match.
- Sets some variables like `ceditf` which are not used in this script, but maybe elsewhere
- If the host matches, two cookies are set, and a navigation occurs (to whatever `api` has as URL)
- Every 5 seconds checks the content of the element with id "creditlink".
- If the contents of "creditlink" are not as expected it calls `invalidLIC`, but that function is empty -- I think that might have had code in a previous version of this script, but it was later removed.